# Vue Warn Error When Binding Route Value from laravel with style using string template

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am working in a Laravel App and am binding a laravel route so that it may be used in a Vue component. I correctly `v-bind` the route in my index.blade.php file and then use it in a bound `:href` in my Vue component but I am getting this error in the console:

Error Vue

```
  [Vue warn]: Error compiling template:

invalid expression: Unexpected token ':' in

    http://myproject.local/classes/4

  Raw expression: v-bind:route="http://myproject.local/classes/4"
```

Route used in my Classes.vue file

```
<a :href="route" target="" class="card-image" :style="{ 'background-image': `url(${invitedClass.imagePath})`}"></a>
```

Route bound and vue component being used in index.blade.php

```
<div id="app">
 <classes :route="{{ route('classes.show',['id' => $invitedClass->id]) }}"></classes>                         
</div>
```

It seems not to like the colon in my vue component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misusing the string template syntax with style binding, it should be like :

```
 :style="`background-image: url(${invitedClass.imagePath})`"
```

or

```
 :style="{ 'background-image': 'url('+invitedClass.imagePath+')'}"
```

Example :

1 -

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
      img: 'https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300'

    }
  }
})
```

```css
#someDiv {
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app" class="container">

  <div id="someDiv" :style="`background-image: url(${img})`">
    lorem ipsum
  </div>

</div>
```

2 -

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
      img: 'https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300'

    }
  }
})
```

```css
#someDiv {
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app" class="container">

  <div id="someDiv"  :style="{ 'background-image': 'url('+img+')'}">
    lorem ipsum
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I am using your 2nd example for the style tag but I am getting the same error. Here is my anchor tag within my Classes.vue ``` <a :href="route" target="" class="card-image"
         :style="{ 'background-image': 'url('+invitedClass.imagePath+')'}"></a>```

Comment: ALso I cannot set an ```img``` property in my vue initialization because the img is being dynamically rendered with ```invitedClass.imagePath``` which was converted from Laravels ```Storage::url($announcement->image_path)```

Comment: the second solution should work please check my second running sample

Comment: What value would I set in the Data property as my image? I am not using a static value for my image. Thanks

Comment: I think the error is actually in relation to my route binding and not the styling. Can you have another look? I updated the error in my question

Comment: try out to remove `:` before route prop

Comment: do you have a moment to chat? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220938/vue

Comment: @PA-GW if you see that this answer is useless i will remove